# How to speed up tree creation

Tags: c#, performance, tree

I have this code to generate a temp tree whose code is as follows

```
object regionSale = regionValue.GetValueAsString();

if (root.Children.Count > 0)
{
    if ((tmpNode.Data.Level) == (levelNested - 1))
    {
        var newChild = new Node
        {
            Data = new NodeData
                    {
                        Level = levelNested,
                        RegionName = elemNested.GetValueAsString(),
                        RegionValue = NAValue.Equals(regionSale.ToString())
                            ? null
                            : (double?)regionValue.GetValueAsFloat64()
                    },
            Parent = tmpNode
        };

        tmpNode.Children.Add(newChild);
        tmpNode = newChild;

    }
    else if (tmpNode.Data.Level == levelNested)
    {
        var node = tmpNode.Parent;
        var newChild = new Node
        {
            Data = new NodeData
                    {
                        Level = levelNested,
                        RegionName = elemNested.GetValueAsString(),
                        RegionValue = NAValue.Equals(regionSale.ToString())
                            ? null
                            : (double?)regionValue.GetValueAsFloat64()
                    },
            Parent = node
        };

        node.Children.Add(newChild);
        tmpNode = newChild;
    }
    else
    {
        var parentNode = tmpNode.Parent;
        while ((parentNode.Data.Level) != (levelNested - 1))
        {
            parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
        }
        var newChild = new Node
        {
            Data = new NodeData
                    {
                        Level = levelNested,
                        RegionName = elemNested.GetValueAsString(),
                        RegionValue = NAValue.Equals(regionSale.ToString())
                            ? null
                            : (double?)regionValue.GetValueAsFloat64()
                    },
            Parent = parentNode
        };

        parentNode.Children.Add(newChild);
        tmpNode = newChild;
    }
}
else
{
    var children = new Node();
    children.Data = new NodeData
    {
        Level = levelNested,
        RegionName = elemNested.GetValueAsString(),
        RegionValue = NAValue.Equals(regionSale.ToString())
            ? null
            : (double?)regionValue.GetValueAsFloat64()
    };

    children.Parent = root;
    root.Children.Add(children);
    tmpNode = children;
}
```

The data passed to this function is a root node like:

```
for (var nestedIndex = 0; nestedIndex < numofBulkValues; nestedIndex++)
{
    var bulkElementNested = refBulkField.GetValueAsElement(nestedIndex);

    var elemNested = bulkElementNested.GetElement(0);
    var levelElement = bulkElementNested.GetElement(1);
    var regionValue = bulkElementNested.GetElement(2);
    var levelNested = levelElement.GetValueAsInt32();

    tmpNode = GenerateTree(root, tmpNode, elemNested, regionValue, levelNested);
}
```

In this situation, the data i get is in the format

```
ADSK UW EQUITY  
Europe, Middle East and Africa  Level=1
The Americas  Level=1
   U.S  Level=2
   Other Americas  Level=2
The Asia/Pacific  Level=1
   Other Asia/Pacific  Level=2
   Japan  Level=2
Reconciliation  Level=1
```

and there are multiple such equities. the problem is that this process is taking a long time almost 9 seconds to do but only takes 16 seconds to display the actual result. Yes, this is the core of the application and very important so it cannot be skipped. Is there any way to reduce the time to create this tree?

my node class is as follows:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {

    }
    public Node(Node node)
        : this()
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        this.Data = new NodeData(node.Data);
        if (node.Children != null)
            this.Children = new List<Node>(node.Children);
        this.Parent = new Node(node.Parent);
    }
    public NodeData Data;
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
    public Node Parent;
}
public class NodeData
{
    public NodeData()
    {

    }
    public NodeData(NodeData nodeData)
        : this()
    {
        if (nodeData == null)
            return;
        this.RegionName = nodeData.RegionName;
        this.RegionValue = nodeData.RegionValue;
        this.Level = nodeData.Level;

    }
    public string RegionName;
    public double? RegionValue;
    public int Level;
}
```

If there is more i can provide please let me know. and thanks for any help

Comment: Profiler will help you to narrow your context little bit (if, just for example!) GetValueAsString() takes 100 msec then you know where you have to look for. At first look (without profiling) I see many many many List<T> operations (and (re)allocations). If list probable size is more or less known...you can start from there (create list with a _reasonable_ initial capacity to prevent reallocations).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti hi, i have checked the profiler, it says that GetValueAsString used <0.1%. But i have put a timer before and after the GenerateTree() and if this function can be optimized then it will shave off a lot of time.

Comment: Getvalueasstring was just an example! Timer? You already have profiler results to inspect...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti also the list size is not known at all as it may vary from 1 execution to the next even for the same equities. there can be many such regions added or removed.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes.. but i was checking if the data pull was the issue or thie tree generation..  the profiler doesn't show much for this function.

Comment: Is there anyway i can change the function itself to reduce the time consumption??

Comment: Yes, if you know what takes time inside it...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti i am not able to figure it out... ill check.. :)

Comment: Try to post first bunch of lines in profiler report.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I have posted an answer as to what i have done.. can you please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

So what i have done is that I have made changes in the Node.cs Class as follows:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {

    }
    public Node(Node node)
        : this()
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        if (node.Children != null)
            this.Children = new List<Node>(node.Children);
        this.Parent = new Node(node.Parent);
        this.RegionName = nodeData.RegionName;
        this.RegionValue = nodeData.RegionValue;
        this.Level = nodeData.Level;
    }
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
    public Node Parent;
    public string RegionName;
    public double? RegionValue;
    public int Level;
}
```

Also i have checked the functions where the log is being recorded, so small functions which get called a lot(for inside for..) i have removed those logs. This all has reduced the time from 4.30 minutes to about 1.30 minutes for 900 equities. But i wanted to ask if there is something more i can do to make it faster.

There is one other problem:
Only for 1 function out of many which pulls the data from the database(sqlite database), connection.Open() takes a lot of time. Can this problem be because the connection is Open for a long time?? or is there a possibility of another connection which is already open,so to close that and start this connection takes time?

Comment: Jay, I wouldn't like to be pedantic but...to know what to do we need to _profile_ your code...logs were a big issue? We didn't even see them...like this is optimizing with glass ball! Lol

Comment: hahaha... i agree.. profiler shows logs as main issue probably because of the IO operations.. so the functions which get called about 100 times having 3 to 4 log lines are a major issue..

Comment: even in profiler, the deeper i go into any function taking time, it just says that the Logger is using a lot of time...  there is just 1 problem i couldn't understand. I will update the answer i have given to include this.